# courgette-jvm configuration no information on the source of the error

Tags: java, parallel-processing, cucumber, testng, courgette

[test result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7p9OD.png)

[runner class](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kuIvN.png)

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
        <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>6.3.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <!--CUCUMBER DEPENDENCIES -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>7.1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java8</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-java</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>${cucumber.version}</version>
    </dependency>
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surfire.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>${maven.surfire.plugin.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

I have no information about the cause of the error. I added courgette dependency to pom.xml. What could be causing the problem?

Comment: Please don't put code as image but prefer copy/paste. Also, can you show your `pom.xml` ?

Comment: I can't add the whole, is it enough?

Comment: Your logs report some test failures. First of all you need to investigate why do the logic fail. We cannot help you unless we have at least full stacktrace and the code where that exception has been thrown.

Answer (score 0):

It seems some issue with your maven goal `test` . You can utilize this below config that I am using to run `courgette-jvm` and `testNG` tests . It uses `failsafe` plugin  and a maven `profile` named `acceptanceTests` . All config is in this profile . The command I use to run this is `mvn clean verify -P acceptanceTests -X` in intelliJ

```
  </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>org.testng</groupId>
        <artifactId>testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.14.3</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>io.cucumber</groupId>
        <artifactId>cucumber-testng</artifactId>
        <version>6.9.1</version>
    </dependency>
          <dependency>
        <groupId>io.github.prashant-ramcharan</groupId>
        <artifactId>courgette-jvm</artifactId>
        <version>5.11.0</version>
    </dependency>
      <dependency>
  <!-- httpclient dpendendecy is to resolve courgette-jvm error -  NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/http/conn/ssl/TrustAllStrategy -->        
 <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
    <artifactId>httpclient</artifactId>
    <version>4.5.10</version>
</dependency>

 <profiles>
<profile>
      <id>acceptanceTests</id>
      <activation>
        <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
      </activation>
      <build>

        <plugins>
             <plugin>
                    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId> 
                    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId> 
                    <version>1.0.0</version> 
                    <executions> 
                        <execution> 
                            <phase>generate-resources</phase> 
                            <goals> 
                                <goal>write-project-properties</goal> 
                            </goals> 
                            <configuration> 
                                <outputFile>${project.build.outputDirectory}/my.properties</outputFile> 
                            </configuration> 
                        </execution> 
                    </executions> 
             </plugin>

 <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-failsafe-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>3.0.0-M5</version>
            <executions>
                 <execution>
                  <id>integration-test</id> 
                <goals>
                  <goal>integration-test</goal>
                  
                </goals>
                     <configuration>
                        <parallel>methods</parallel>
                         <threadCount>4</threadCount>
                        <useUnlimitedThreads>true</useUnlimitedThreads>
                           <systemPropertyVariables>
                                <hub.port>${hub.p}</hub.port>
                                 
                          </systemPropertyVariables>
                      </configuration>
              </execution>
         
            </executions>
   
          </plugin>
           <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <configuration>
          <source>8</source>
          <target>8</target>
        </configuration>
             
      </plugin>
           
              <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-report-plugin</artifactId>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>post-integration-test</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>failsafe-report-only</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
  </plugins>
  
  </build>

</profile>
 </profiles>
```

Runner class is

```
@Test
@CourgetteOptions(
        threads = 10,
        runLevel = CourgetteRunLevel.SCENARIO,
        rerunFailedScenarios = true,
        rerunAttempts = 1,
        showTestOutput = true,
        reportTitle = "Courgette-JVM Example",
        reportTargetDir = "build",
        environmentInfo = "browser=chrome; git_branch=master",
        cucumberOptions = @CucumberOptions(
                features = "src/test/resources/com/test/",
                
                glue = "com.test.stepdefs",                  
                tags = {"@firefox or @chrome"},                                     
                publish = true,
                plugin = {
                        "pretty",
                        "json:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.json",
                        "html:target/cucumber-report/cucumber.html"}
        ))
class AcceptanceIT extends TestNGCourgette {
}
```